# Is there a way to all properties of an object that begins with a string

Tags: javascript, object

I am making a random meal generator that uses the API [The mealdb](https://www.themealdb.com) and the results that come back are something like this.

```
{
  "idMeal": "52802",
  "strMeal": "Fish pie",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Seafood",
  "strArea": "British",
  "strInstructions": "01.Put the potatoes in a large pan of cold salted water and bring to the boil. Lower the heat, cover, then simmer gently for 15 minutes until tender. Drain, then return to the pan over a low heat for 30 seconds to drive off any excess water. Mash with 1 tbsp olive oil, then season.\r\n02.Meanwhile put the milk in a large sauté pan, add the fish and bring to the boil. Remove from the heat, cover and stand for 3 minutes. Remove the fish (reserving the milk) and pat dry with kitchen paper, then gently flake into an ovenproof dish, discarding the skin and any bones.\r\n03.Heat the remaining oil in a pan, stir in the flour and cook for 30 seconds. Gradually stir in 200-250ml of the reserved milk (discard the rest). Grate in nutmeg, season, then bubble until thick. Stir in the cream.\r\n04.Preheat the oven to 190°C/fan170°C/gas 5. Grate the artichokes and add to the dish with the leek, prawns and herbs. Stir the lemon zest and juice into the sauce, then pour over. Mix gently with a wooden spoon.\r\n05.Spoon the mash onto the fish mixture, then use a fork to make peaks, which will crisp and brown as it cooks. Sprinkle over the cheese, then bake for 35-40 minutes until golden and bubbling. Serve with wilted greens.",
  "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/ysxwuq1487323065.jpg",
  "strTags": "Fish,Pie,Breakfast,Baking",
  "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sX4fCgg-UI",
  "strIngredient1": "Floury Potatoes",
  "strIngredient2": "Olive Oil",
  "strIngredient3": "Semi-skimmed Milk",
  "strIngredient4": "White Fish Fillets",
  "strIngredient5": "Plain flour",
  "strIngredient6": "Nutmeg",
  "strIngredient7": "Double Cream",
  "strIngredient8": "Jerusalem Artichokes",
  "strIngredient9": "Leek",
  "strIngredient10": "Prawns",
  "strIngredient11": "Parsley",
  "strIngredient12": "Dill",
  "strIngredient13": "Lemon",
  "strIngredient14": "Gruyère",
  "strIngredient15": "Lemon",
  "strIngredient16": "",
  "strIngredient17": "",
  "strIngredient18": "",
  "strIngredient19": "",
  "strIngredient20": "",
  "strMeasure1": "900g",
  "strMeasure2": "2 tbsp",
  "strMeasure3": "600ml",
  "strMeasure4": "800g",
  "strMeasure5": "1 tbsp",
  "strMeasure6": "Grating",
  "strMeasure7": "3 tbsp",
  "strMeasure8": "200g",
  "strMeasure9": "1 finely sliced",
  "strMeasure10": "200g peeled raw",
  "strMeasure11": "Large handful",
  "strMeasure12": "Handful",
  "strMeasure13": "Grated zest of 1",
  "strMeasure14": "25g grated",
  "strMeasure15": "Juice of 1",
  "strMeasure16": "",
  "strMeasure17": "",
  "strMeasure18": "",
  "strMeasure19": "",
  "strMeasure20": "",
  "strSource": "",
  "dateModified": null
}
```

I want to be able to iterate through the ingredients not the whole object so i can make them into a list but the ingredients aren't in a single array so i cant iterate only through them.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: use `Object.keys(yourObject).sort()` to get the keys sorted by alphanumeric order. then you can iterate over that and select from the object.

Comment: @r3wt I only want to iterate through the strIngredient<number> not the whole object

Comment: Like described in the link from @RobertHarvey, but with a little addition:

`var ingredients = [];
for (const property in object) {
  if(property.startsWith('strIngredient')){
    ingredients.push(object[property]);
  }
}
console.log(ingredients);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key7values as new array. Use on this array [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the keyword at the start of your key.

```
Object.entries(arr).filter(([key,value]) => key.indexOf('strIngredient')===0);
```

Here the hole snippet for testing.

```js
let arr = {
  "idMeal": "52802",
  "strMeal": "Fish pie",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Seafood",
  "strArea": "British",
  "strInstructions": "01.Put the potatoes in a large pan of cold salted water and bring to the boil. Lower the heat, cover, then simmer gently for 15 minutes until tender. Drain, then return to the pan over a low heat for 30 seconds to drive off any excess water. Mash with 1 tbsp olive oil, then season.\r\n02.Meanwhile put the milk in a large sauté pan, add the fish and bring to the boil. Remove from the heat, cover and stand for 3 minutes. Remove the fish (reserving the milk) and pat dry with kitchen paper, then gently flake into an ovenproof dish, discarding the skin and any bones.\r\n03.Heat the remaining oil in a pan, stir in the flour and cook for 30 seconds. Gradually stir in 200-250ml of the reserved milk (discard the rest). Grate in nutmeg, season, then bubble until thick. Stir in the cream.\r\n04.Preheat the oven to 190°C/fan170°C/gas 5. Grate the artichokes and add to the dish with the leek, prawns and herbs. Stir the lemon zest and juice into the sauce, then pour over. Mix gently with a wooden spoon.\r\n05.Spoon the mash onto the fish mixture, then use a fork to make peaks, which will crisp and brown as it cooks. Sprinkle over the cheese, then bake for 35-40 minutes until golden and bubbling. Serve with wilted greens.",
  "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/ysxwuq1487323065.jpg",
  "strTags": "Fish,Pie,Breakfast,Baking",
  "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sX4fCgg-UI",
  "strIngredient1": "Floury Potatoes",
  "strIngredient2": "Olive Oil",
  "strIngredient3": "Semi-skimmed Milk",
  "strIngredient4": "White Fish Fillets",
  "strIngredient5": "Plain flour",
  "strIngredient6": "Nutmeg",
  "strIngredient7": "Double Cream",
  "strIngredient8": "Jerusalem Artichokes",
  "strIngredient9": "Leek",
  "strIngredient10": "Prawns",
  "strIngredient11": "Parsley",
  "strIngredient12": "Dill",
  "strIngredient13": "Lemon",
  "strIngredient14": "Gruyère",
  "strIngredient15": "Lemon",
  "strIngredient16": "",
  "strIngredient17": "",
  "strIngredient18": "",
  "strIngredient19": "",
  "strIngredient20": "",
  "strMeasure1": "900g",
  "strMeasure2": "2 tbsp",
  "strMeasure3": "600ml",
  "strMeasure4": "800g",
  "strMeasure5": "1 tbsp",
  "strMeasure6": "Grating",
  "strMeasure7": "3 tbsp",
  "strMeasure8": "200g",
  "strMeasure9": "1 finely sliced",
  "strMeasure10": "200g peeled raw",
  "strMeasure11": "Large handful",
  "strMeasure12": "Handful",
  "strMeasure13": "Grated zest of 1",
  "strMeasure14": "25g grated",
  "strMeasure15": "Juice of 1",
  "strMeasure16": "",
  "strMeasure17": "",
  "strMeasure18": "",
  "strMeasure19": "",
  "strMeasure20": "",
  "strSource": "",
  "dateModified": null
};

let res = Object.entries(arr).filter(([key,value]) => key.indexOf('strIngredient')===0);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one where I loop through all keys and `slice` 2 contents from it to match the `strIngredient` word

```js
yourobject = {
  "idMeal": "52802",
  "strMeal": "Fish pie",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Seafood",
  "strArea": "British",
  "strInstructions": "01.Put the potatoes in a large pan of cold salted water and bring to the boil. Lower the heat, cover, then simmer gently for 15 minutes until tender. Drain, then return to the pan over a low heat for 30 seconds to drive off any excess water. Mash with 1 tbsp olive oil, then season.\r\n02.Meanwhile put the milk in a large sauté pan, add the fish and bring to the boil. Remove from the heat, cover and stand for 3 minutes. Remove the fish (reserving the milk) and pat dry with kitchen paper, then gently flake into an ovenproof dish, discarding the skin and any bones.\r\n03.Heat the remaining oil in a pan, stir in the flour and cook for 30 seconds. Gradually stir in 200-250ml of the reserved milk (discard the rest). Grate in nutmeg, season, then bubble until thick. Stir in the cream.\r\n04.Preheat the oven to 190°C/fan170°C/gas 5. Grate the artichokes and add to the dish with the leek, prawns and herbs. Stir the lemon zest and juice into the sauce, then pour over. Mix gently with a wooden spoon.\r\n05.Spoon the mash onto the fish mixture, then use a fork to make peaks, which will crisp and brown as it cooks. Sprinkle over the cheese, then bake for 35-40 minutes until golden and bubbling. Serve with wilted greens.",
  "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/ysxwuq1487323065.jpg",
  "strTags": "Fish,Pie,Breakfast,Baking",
  "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sX4fCgg-UI",
  "strIngredient1": "Floury Potatoes",
  "strIngredient2": "Olive Oil",
  "strIngredient3": "Semi-skimmed Milk",
  "strIngredient4": "White Fish Fillets",
  "strIngredient5": "Plain flour",
  "strIngredient6": "Nutmeg",
  "strIngredient7": "Double Cream",
  "strIngredient8": "Jerusalem Artichokes",
  "strIngredient9": "Leek",
  "strIngredient10": "Prawns",
  "strIngredient11": "Parsley",
  "strIngredient12": "Dill",
  "strIngredient13": "Lemon",
  "strIngredient14": "Gruyère",
  "strIngredient15": "Lemon",
  "strIngredient16": "",
  "strIngredient17": "",
  "strIngredient18": "",
  "strIngredient19": "",
  "strIngredient20": "",
  "strMeasure1": "900g",
  "strMeasure2": "2 tbsp",
  "strMeasure3": "600ml",
  "strMeasure4": "800g",
  "strMeasure5": "1 tbsp",
  "strMeasure6": "Grating",
  "strMeasure7": "3 tbsp",
  "strMeasure8": "200g",
  "strMeasure9": "1 finely sliced",
  "strMeasure10": "200g peeled raw",
  "strMeasure11": "Large handful",
  "strMeasure12": "Handful",
  "strMeasure13": "Grated zest of 1",
  "strMeasure14": "25g grated",
  "strMeasure15": "Juice of 1",
  "strMeasure16": "",
  "strMeasure17": "",
  "strMeasure18": "",
  "strMeasure19": "",
  "strMeasure20": "",
  "strSource": "",
  "dateModified": null
}
strIngredient = []
for (let key in yourobject) {
  if (key.slice(0, -2) == 'strIngredien' || key.slice(0, -2) == 'strIngredient') {
    strIngredient.push(yourobject[key])
  }
}
console.log(strIngredient)
```